# Unbalanced TTS error with inter-company salesorder at the "Overwrite prices and discounts" dialog

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta, ax

I am experiencing a critical error when i try to change some sales order lines in a specific intercompany sales order.

When i try to update my order i get presented with a "Overwrite prices and discounts"-dialog:

[image: Overwrite prices and discounts]

If i try to press OK or Cancel, AX throws a Transaction tracking error.

> An unbalanced X++ TTSBEGIN/TTSCOMMIT pair has been detected. Causes of
>   this include (a) too many/few TTSBEGIN  or TTSCOMMIT, (b) return calls
>   within TTSBEGIN/TTSCOMMIT pairs, and (c) user interaction within
>   TTSBEGIN/TTSCOMMIT pairs.
>
> The current TTS level is '5'.

I did some digging around with the debugger and found that official code from Microsoft is doing something like this:

1. Stack up some TTS
2. Change to buying company
3. Display dialog
4. As a result of the dialog, the TTS gets confused and all kinds of wierd things starts happening.

How can i either:

1. Fix it.
2. Disable the dialog all together and have it execute some default behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

A dialog cannot be shown to a user within a TTSBEGIN - TTSCOMMIT pair in AX 2012.

The related MSDN is here;

[X++ Standards: ttsBegin and ttsCommit (AX 2012)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa609617.aspx)

I can understand why microsoft would want to do this, as a required user interation between a pair can cause performance issues, specifically database locks. Business logic should also be completely separate from the UI, and therefore user interaction.

I would fix it if I were you. If the dialog is required, gather the information from the user before you TTSBEGIN, ready for use later.

As you suggest this is official code from Microsoft, I would also suggest you check the latest CU to ensure it has not already been fixed, and if it has not file a bug report.